# Подскажите правильный подход

Tags: django, python-3.6

Есть несколько интернет магазинов. Нужно создать отдельную страницу поиска по этим всем сайтам одновременно для экономии времени. Подскажите правильный подход.

Comment: бд одна или у каждого своя?

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сделал так (из условия, что интернет магазины левые и ты к ним отношения не имеешь, они просто находятся в сети), человек заходит на страницу с поиском по магазинам отправляет POST запрос с нужными критериями на сервер. Дальше самое сложное, прежде чем вернуть ответ мы отправляем запросы **Response** на все нужные интернет магазины ,было бы очень удобно если бы у них был реализован API, если он не реализован то придется парсить данные с их сайта в формате JSON (для удобства). Дальше полученные данные ты преобразовываешь так, как тебе надо для шаблона. И возвращаешь в ответ на его запрос шаблон с готовыми результатами поиска. Для быстроты я бы 100% использовал асинхронные запросы к интернет магазинам (это как минимум).